# std::vector, element pointer and input interator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I don't have my copy of Meyer's Effective C++ with me, so please forgive the question.

```
template <class InputIterator>
    void insert ( iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last );
```

For vector's `insert`, is a byte* to a raw memory block a valid `InputIterator`?

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
vector<byte> my_vector;

byte my_data[NNN];
const byte* first = my_data;
const byte* last = my_data + COUNTOF(my_data);

my_vector.insert(my_vector.end(), first, last);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a pointer is an input iterator.